# Как отключить автоматическую попытку подключиться к базе в spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jpa

Здравствуйте.

У меня мавен проект на Spring Boot. Он состоит из нескольких модулей.

1ый модуль.

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  @Column(name = "city")
  private String city;
  // ...........................
}
```

Чтобы аннотации работали, подключена такая библиотека.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

---

Затем я импортирую этот модуль в другой модуль, чтобы пользоваться ими как обычными простыми классами, делать коллекции и т.д.
Но ушлый spring boot, видимо, увидев аннотации (и библиотеку), начинает крашится и писать, что не настроено подключение к базе, хотя мне не нужно иметь настроенное подключение к базе в этом модуле.

```
2017-07-20 22:47:22 [main] WARN  o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
2017-07-20 22:47:22 [main] INFO  o.a.catalina.core.StandardService - Stopping service Tomcat
```

Уубирать аннотации я не хочу, потому что они нужны для 3его модуля, в котором они используются.

Как я могу запретить ему пытаться подключиться к базе?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась заменой этой библиотеки

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

на эту

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```